# Crumbs not adding home link to beginning

Tags: breadcrumbs

I have installed [Crumbs](https://drupal.org/project/crumbs) on the site I am currently working on and for some reason I can't get it to display the "Home" link.

I have tried debugging some of the nodes and according to the results the home link should be displayed.

The home link is definitely enabled and there isn't any CSS or anything like that which may be interfering with it, am I missing something?

Comment: Which theme are you using? Maybe your theme has its own implementation of theme_breadcrumb, and does not show the home link?

Comment: Otherwise, breadcrumb items are generally skipped (not shown) if Crumbs cannot determine a title for this item or the title is empty. Usually, the Home item should get its title from the crumbs.home_title plugin.

Answer (score 1):

How to find out why not seeing the home link in bredcrums Drupal 8.

1. Check your theme (admin/appearance/settings/THEMENAME)

   Some themes like bootstrap can set to show or not.
2. Check modules for any 'hook_system_breadcrumb_alter'

   These can alter how bredcrums work.
3. Check modules for any services tagged with - "{ name: breadcrumb_builder" (same as above)
4. Check theme templates for any templates overriding core bredcrums or .theme overrides
5. Check if the block is enabled (admin/structure/block)
6. Cry

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what the cause of the problem was, but this was solved by using jQuery to prepend a "Home" link to the start of the breadcrumbs list.

Comment: Hi! I understand this works ok for you, but if you already share this on stackexchange you maybe want to get to the root of the problem, so your answer will be useful for others?